# Why UnityWebRequest is not working for azurewebsites.net where local server is working

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Called API to fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxT2S.png) [prepare jason data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAm6J.png)  I have code to use UnityWebRequest to call a Api. Its worked okay when i used local api url but its get issues when used azure url. Debugging it and get 500 response code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nA-G3hi36PuJibFoPw5UbokpBxg09p8P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could Azure required some authentication key?

Comment: Difference in date format?

Comment: @BugFinder I think date formate is okay. Otherwise local server would get same issues. As local server has worked that means something happened with Azure sever.

Comment: @fafase Yes, here Azure required some authentication key: configuration.APP.AzureBlobAccessKey = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mfcbackupvault;AccountKey=EE3uzm2Lh/pZ6E7XIsapmpPt/MP9uGYJ/YXak+T09+3DxkGnQltK70CKb8U0dr7FW8UoYEjqu4ztgeiI0C4HIA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";